# Angular2 Linkedin redirect uri

Tags: angular, linkedin-api

I am following the RESTful api linkedin docs and I am a bit confused on how to handle the redirection to and from linkedin, I have it working now where in my html.

linkedInAuth.component.html

```
(click)="linkedInAuthorization()"
```

Then in my linkedInAuth.component.ts I just redirect out of my app to linkedin auth which is successful.But I am not sure if this is the best approach because I do not like my options from handling the redirect from here.

```
export class LinkedInAuthComponent {

linkedInAuthorization(){
        window.location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=88myid888&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/dashboard&state=234123rweqwe';
    }
}
```

Then in my dashboard.component.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent  implements OnInit{
    code: string;
    state: string;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let code = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['code']
        let state = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['state']
        console.log(code);
        console.log(state);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have Angular2 hand of the linkedIn uri to a service that will handle the redirect that is specified in linkedin(localhost:3000/dashboard) and save the data to my database without using a component? I would think the better approach would be giving this to a service from the point of the redirect in the linkedInAuthComponent. Not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this component for enabling OAuth2 in Angular2? It looks promising:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-oauth2

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a medium article yesterday, actually, over a similar issue.

Don't use window. When angular released Angular Universal, it renders the template server side initially for performance and SEO reasons. In doing so, it loses reference to the window object.

Here is my article https://medium.com/@D_ofashandfire/i-love-hate-linkedin-oauth-2d7b602926c6

tldr, is that the SDK is really broken in this instance. I find that there it is much easier and simpler to use the REST API and then receive the auth code via server side implementation.

Here is an example component.

https://gist.github.com/dashcraft/4b3853e558eaec656123342d1174912c

When the redirect comes back it will come back to your redirect url with the param "code". So you can parse that in your router as a optional query param on your url.